# How do I read the output of a curl into a ruby variable?

Tags: ruby, curl, stdout, puts

Say I have the following `curl` call :

```
"curl  -v --insecure -X POST -H 'Host: api.test.com' -H 'Tester #{@@test_name}' -d 'token=#{token_raw}' https://teststage.BLAHBLAH:token/terminate"
```

I'm trying to get the output of the curl call. Such as the `200 OK` or `404 ERROR` status.

So, if I do :

```
a = `curl  -v --insecure -X POST -H 'Host: api.test.com' -H 'Tester #{@@test_name}' -d 'token=#{token_raw}' https://teststage.BLAHBLAH:token/terminate`
```

I get nothing back in `a`

However, if I do

```
puts `curl  -v --insecure -X POST -H 'Host: api.test.com' -H 'Tester #{@@test_name}' -d 'token=#{token_raw}' https://teststage.BLAHBLAH:token/terminate`
```

Then I can see the output. How do I read it into the variable. I'd prefer an answer without any import like OPEN3, if possible.

Comment: Have you tried: `a = ``curl "blah.blah"`` - Does anyone know how to escape backticks?

Comment: As in the variable is also in backticks? Or just add a backtick to the variable?

`a = `curl "blah.blah"`` ??

Comment: That's another question right there. I think `\``

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why

```rb
a = `curl  -v --insecure -X POST -H 'Host: api.test.com' -H 'Tester #{@@test_name}' -d 'token=#{token_raw}' https://teststage.BLAHBLAH:token/terminate`
```

isn't working for you.

Here's what I get with a simpler test:

```rb
RUBY_VERSION # => "1.9.3"

`curl --version`
# => "curl 7.30.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0) libcurl/7.30.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5\nProtocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp \nFeatures: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz \n"

a = `curl http://echo.jsontest.com/hello/world`

a # => "{\"hello\": \"world\"}\n"
```

**UPDATE**

I missed a part of your question and didn't realize you were looking for the headers.

Try this:

```rb
a = `curl -I http://echo.jsontest.com/hello/world`
a.lines.first # => "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: So, my update is literally that if I get a 404 error, I get some random JSON back.

If it works, blank. That's how I'm working with it.

Comment: Technically no. But I guess I could live with it. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, upon re-reading your question. I misunderstood part of it. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to just use [Ethon](https://github.com/typhoeus/ethon) to interface with libcurl instead of calling out to the shell interface, especially if you're unwilling to use the tools Ruby gives you for interfacing with the shell and other processes more readily (you know, like [Open3](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html)).

Note: the Ruby standard library (including Open3) is part of Ruby and distributed with it. It is in no sense an import, but if you really don't want to use the `require` method for some inane reason, `IO` is available without loading additional code and provides the low level interface that Open3 utilizes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
HTTP_RESP_CODE=$(curl -s -o out.html -w '%{http_code}' http://www.example.com)

echo $HTTP_RESP_CODE
```

This works with my `ruby`.

```
HTTP_RESP_CODE=`curl -s -o out.html -w '%{http_code}' http://www.example.com`
print HTTP_RESP_CODE
```

Comment: t.ruby:1: `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name
t.ruby:1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
@@r = $(curl  -v --insecure -X POST ...

Comment: @gran_profaci no idea about it. You can try to put my example curl command inisde the \`...\` instead of `$(...)`

Comment: Same Error. This is a syntax problem apparently.

Comment: @gran_profaci I have just checked the code with ruby(see updated answer) and it works. May be your problem is at elsewhere!